# Exception handling in async Methods MVC. How to use try catch for method called using await?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

```
     [HttpPost]
 public async Task<JsonResult>    
    {
     await sendNotification(responce);
    }
```

I want to catch exception occured in sendnotification method.
How can I call the same using Task.Factory ??

Comment: The caller needs to handle the exceptions - they are wrapped by the `Task` and sent back in the result (check `Task.Result`). Obviously you can try/catch inside the method and throw the appropriate exception

Answer (score 2):

You just write a `try`/`catch` block, as such:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult>    
{
  try
  {
    await sendNotification(responce);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

You don't need `Task.Factory` for this.

Comment: I do this but nothing happens, the exception that is thrown is a ```Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)``` and any evidence of the real exception is lost as inner exception is null.

Comment: @simbolo: Please post a repro and the exception details as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Exception Handling of **sendNotification()** task depends on how the task is coded. In one way, above Stephen Cleary's answer is right but not sure it fixes your issue.

You can go through below easy understandable articles to understand Exception Handling in Async programming...

[Basic exception handling in Asynchronious programming in C#.](http://www.thecsharp.com/Articles/15/Basic-exception-handling-in-Asynchronious-programming-in-CSharp)

[Exception object behaves differently while handling exceptions in parallel tasks in Asynchronous programming.](http://www.thecsharp.com/Articles/16/Exception-object-behaves-differently-while-handling-exceptions-in-parallel-tasks-in-asynchronious-programming-CSharp)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Also look into below link..

[Handling the AggregateException using Handle method in Asynchronous programming.](http://www.thecsharp.com/Articles/17/Handling-the-AggregateException-using-Handle-method-in-asynchronous-programming-in-CSharp)

Comment: Please avoid link only answers, they have no value if link get broken.